# Создайте массив С из элементов массива А кратных 3. Найдите сумму и количество элементов нового массива. В чем ошибка?

Tags: c#, c++, массивы, кодировка, информатика

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int A[] = {2, 3, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15};
int n = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);
int C[n], sum_C=0, count_C=0;

for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
if(A[i]%3==0){
C[count_C] = A[i];
count_C++;
sum_C += A[i];
}
}

cout«"Array C: ";
for(int i=0; i<count_C; i++){
cout«C[i]«" ";
}
cout«endl;
cout«"Sum of C: "«sum_C«endl;
cout«"Count of C: "«count_C«endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: нет, это вы должны написать, в чём именно вы видите ошибку. а уж кто-нибудь после этого может объяснить вам, отчего эта ошибка происходит.

Answer (score 1):

В общем-то только две: оператор `<<` — это не символ "открывающие кавычки", а два символа "меньше", а вторая — не

```
int n = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);
```

а

```
const int n = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);
```

или даже (С++ все же...)

```
constexpr int n = size(A);
```